# how can i pass json array from php file on a server to my ionic app?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework, xmlhttprequest

i'm developing an Ionic app and i must pass data from backend (php file on a server) to ionic app and from ionic app to backend.
I tried this:

```
.controller('AppCtrl',function($scope,$ionicPlatform,$location,$http,$ionicHisto
ry, $ionicModal, $timeout,$cordovaSQLite) {


$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){


$http.get('http://http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/json.php')
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
          var user = data;
          for(i = 0; i<user.length; i++){
            var cell = user[i].cell;
            var nome = user[i].nome;
            var cognome = user[i].cognome;
            var mail = user[i].mail;
            var codF = user[i].codF;
            var pwd = user[i].pwd;
          }
    }
});
```

I know i must use http request but i don't know how, can someone help me?
Thank's

Comment: is this a TYPO http://http://localhost/ShuttleFIX/json.php

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to determine is how you return and receive data from your server php. Define the method `GET` or `POST`, if GET you must assemble the URL with the parameters you want to send. If Post, they are usually shipped with JSON format and pass in the parameter `data`

It seems not beam tried a lot but is more or less like this:

GET :

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    var url = "http://myhost/name="+$scope.name;
    $http({ method: 'GET', url: url, dataType: "json", contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
    .error(function(response) {
        console.log("error");
    })
    .finally(function() {

    });
})
```

POST:

```
    var data = {
         name : $scope.name
    }
    $http({ method: 'POST', url: url, dataType: "json", data: data})
    .success(function(data) {

    })
    .error(function(response) {
          console.log("error");
    })
    .finally(function() {

    });
```